# XMLHttpRequest error when updating document, but CORS should be enabled

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

When I try to update a record I get these CORS errors:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/api/adverts/5bf2b76c38c88dd144e5d4c3 due to access control checks.
```

In create.component.ts:

```
onSaveAdvert(form: NgForm){
    if (form.invalid) {
        console.log("fail");
        return;
    }
    console.log(form.value.title);
    this.advertService.updateAdvert(this.id, form.value.title, form.value.content, form.value.make, form.value.model, form.value.color, form.value.price, form.value.milage, form.value.doors, form.value.year, null);
    console.log("succes");
    form.resetForm();
}
```

Update function in advert.service.ts:

```
updateAdvert(id: string, title: string, content: string, make: string, model: string, color: string, price: number, milage: number, doors: number, year: number, addedOn: any){
    const advert: Advert = {_id: id, title: title, content: content, make: make, model: model, color: color, price: price, milage: milage, doors: doors, year: year, addedOn: null};
    this.http.put("localhost:3000/api/adverts/" + id, advert)
        .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
}
```

Express endpoint in app.js:

```
app.put("/api/adverts/:id", (req, res, next)=>{
    const advert = new Advert({
        _id: req.body.id,
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        make: req.body.make,
        model: req.body.model,
        color: req.body.color,
        price: req.body.price,
        milage: req.body.milage,
        doors: req.body.doors,
        year: req.body.year
    })
    Advert.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, advert).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json({message: "succesful"});
    });
});
```

Setting Headers in app.js:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    next();
});
```

It seems to be a CORS problem, but I can GET, POST and DELETE records in the database, but updating throws these errors.

UPDATE:
I replaced:

```
this.http.put("localhost:3000/api/adverts/" + id, advert)
```

With:

```
this.http.put(`${this.uri}/api/adverts/${id}`, advert)
```

in updateAdvert() in advert.service.ts.

The console now shows nothing in the client but I get a mongoDB error which I need to fix before an update can actually happen.

Comment: *updating throws these errors* – please show us what the update request looks like (what http method does it use, the headers, the body; the relevant js is after *Update function in advert.service.ts*, right?). Basically it sounds like GET, POST and DELETE work but PUT doesn't, right?

Comment: I logged the entire req object and found this:   body:
   { price: 54325432,
     milage: 5432543,
     title: 'KAAS',
     content: 'test,
     make: 'test',
     model: 'test',
     color: 'test',
     doors:'1',
     year: '1' },
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
  route:
   Route {
     path: '/api/adverts/:id',
     stack:
      [ Layer {
        <-cut->
          keys: [],
          regexp: { /^\/?$/i fast_star: false, fast_slash: false },
          method: 'put' } ],
     methods: { put: true } } }

Comment: I also found this error and I'm going to figure this one out now.
(node:54147) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

Not sure if it is related

Comment: have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cors node js library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors):

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Add cors to handlers:

```
app.get('/products/:id', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled'})
});
```

Comment: I already had the second line as "const app = express();" 

The two other lines changed nothing and yes, cors was installed.

Comment: You also need add cors to handlers. I update my answer

Comment: The handlers are only needed when applying CORS to one route only. "app.use(cors());" should handle it globally, but it doesn't